# I want to suppress "no access to tty" error message?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have a bash script where I use `ssh` to connect to another server and run some commands there. I found some sites that the error (`Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.`) is a friendly message but my bash script gets "stuck". No other commands are executed after this message appears. Other forums said to use `ssh -t` to suppress the message but its not working for me. My code looks something like this:

```
.
.
.
stty -echo
sshpass "pwd" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no usr@1.1.1.1 'su -lc "rm -rf tmp"' 2>/dev/null
stty echo
.
.
.
```

The reason why I'm using `stty-echo` is because I need to switch users to root and the password is displayed on the terminal (which I don't want). I get the error message (`Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor). Thus no job control in this shell.`) after I enter the password for root on the connect server (ip: 1.1.1.1).

Any suggestions? Let me know if further explanation is required. Thanks!
(My version of bash is GNU bash version 3.2.51(1))

**EDIT**

The error message I get when removing `2>/dev/null` is:

```
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell. 
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
```

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I did strip down the code as much as possible. The error message I'm getting is with this code. I'm unsure of what you mean

Comment: Sorry, I meant as much as possible so that the error still occurs. I think the problem will not go away if you remove the ` 2>/dev/null`? But it may hide messages that would help us!

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I will edit the question to give the message I get without `2>/dev/null`

Comment: Adding a `-T` to your `ssh` command change things? `ssh -To ...`.

Comment: How do you run your script? Do you run it in a terminal?

Comment: Do you really need to give su the -l option? That's going to run the remote shell's login and per-instance init files, which, unsurprisingly, assume they're running on a terminal.

Comment: @Alias: Does it run when you don't use `sshpass`, but use `ssh -t`?

Comment: @slm Still getting the same error

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I am running the script in a terminal

Comment: I think it may depend on what the input of the script is connected to, so what is the exact command?

Comment: @Gnouc Still getting the same error

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Could you clarify? Its a bash script running on the terminal of suse linux enterprise

Comment: Do you have the access to create an alternative superuser account on the remote, one that doesn't have `csh` or `tcsh` as its shell? I'd like to try to eliminate the cause of error messages rather than suppress all remote error messages, because some error messages you may actually want to see.

Comment: It could be that you run it like `./myscript.sh`, or `echo foo | myscript.sh | less`, for example?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I'd to eliminate the problem as well. Unfortunately I don't have access to create a superuser. The only superuser is root. What are `csh` or `tcsh`?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel I run the script like this: `./myscript.sh`

Comment: csh and tcsh are shells, like bash but different. They are mostly used by older BSD systems, and rarely on Linux. The error message **Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor)** is coming from them. It looks like either root on the remote side has csh or tcsh as its shell, or one of root's init files is running a csh or tcsh script.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I have `tcsh` version 6.15.00 (Astron). Since I'm a beginner with Linux, how do I make sure the the shell being used is bash? How would I change the root's init files to run with bash?

Comment: I don't know of an automated way to translate csh/tcsh init files to bash init files. You need to do it by hand. (Luckily, they all have different names - .login, .tcshrc, .cshrc, .profile, .bash_profile, .bashrc) so you won't need to overwrite anything). Converting them may merit a separate question here if you need assistance beyond the documentation. Then, after that, the command to change change the shell depends on the OS; is the system with tcsh Linux, FreeBSD, Windows running Cygwin, or something else?

Comment: Is `/dev/pts` mounted ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether `stdin` is a terminal before using `stty`:

```
if [[ -t 0 ]]; then stty -echo; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to securely hide your password and root's from the terminal, why not use a ssh key-pair? If you run the `ssh-keygen` command you can generate an crypto.pub key that if you place in every remote host's `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` file you can then just execute your command like such: `ssh root@1.1.1.1 "rm -rf tmp"`. This way you don't have to ever visibly type your password again. The command if you wanted, could then also be added to the crontab and set on a regular schedule so that you can spend your time doing other things. This is all assuming that the machine you are generating the key from, only you have access to, or to be more clear, the user account on the machine you are generating the key from is not a shared account between you a sudo user and a non-sudo user.

If this helps but need a better explanation let me know and I will try to add more information to my answer.

This may help if you have never generated a key-pair before: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/